# Error while running angularJS unit test case in Karma-Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

**MainCtrl.js**

```
var app = angular.module('mailApp');
  app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http) {
  $scope.sortType     = 'date'; // set the default sort type
  $scope.sortReverse  = false;  // set the default sort order
  $scope.inboxDetails = [];

  $scope.loadInboxData = function(a){
      if(a==1){
         $http.get('inboxData.json')
       .then(function(response){
          $scope.inboxData = response.data;          
    });}
      else if(a==2){
         $http.get('inboxData1.json')
       .then(function(response){
          $scope.inboxData = response.data;          
    });}

  }


//-----------------------------------------------
```

**testMainCtrl.js**

```
'use strict';

describe('MainCtrl', function () {
 var $controller;

 beforeEach(module('mailApp'));

     beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
       $controller = _$controller_;
    }));

    //Test cases to verify Inbox Data

    describe('$scope.loadInboxData', function () {

        it('Inbox data is called', function () {
            var $scope = {};
            var controller = $controller('MainCtrl', {$scope: $scope});

            $scope.inboxData = [{"subject": "Angular Example 11", "date": "3/8/2016", "to": "test1", "from":"abcd1","details":"Test Message 1" },{ "subject": "Angular Example 21", "date": "3/8/2016", "to": "test2", "from":"abcd2","details":"Test Message 2" },{ "subject": "Angular Example 31", "date": "4/8/2016", "to": "test3", "from":"abcd3","details":"Test Message 3" },{ "subject": "Angular Example 41", "date": "5/8/2016", "to": "test3", "from":"abcd4","details":"Test Message 4" }];

            var a=$scope.loadInboxData(1);
            expect($scope.inboxData).toEqual(a);

        }); 
    });


});

//------------------------------------------------
```

**Error :**

> Chrome 48.0.2564 (Windows 10 0.0.0) MainCtrl $scope.loadInboxData
>   Inbox data is called FAILED

Expected

```
[  
   Object(   {  
      subject:'Angular Example 11',
      date:'3/8/2016',
      to:'test1',
      from:'abcd1',
      details:'Test Message 1'
   }   ),
   Object(   {  
      subject:'Angular Example 21',
      date:'3/8/2016',
      to:'test2',
      from:'abcd2',
      details:'Test Message 2'
   }   ),
   Object(   {  
      subject:'Angular Example 31',
      date:'4/8/2016',
      to:'test3',
      from:'abcd3',
      details:'Test Message 3'
   }   ),
   Object(   {  
      subject:'Angular Example 41',
      date:'5/8/2016',
      to:'test3',
      from:'abcd4',
      details:'Test Message 4'
   }   )
]
```

to equal undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a hard dependency on $http in your test. You should mock a return value from the $http service.

Take a look at the documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you, $httpBackend is mock of $http

```
'use strict';

describe('MainCtrl', function () {
 var $controller,$httpBackend;

 beforeEach(module('mailApp'));

     beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
       $controller = _$controller_;
    }));
    beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {

      $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');

    }));

    //Test cases to verify Inbox Data

    describe('$scope.loadInboxData', function () {

        it('Inbox data is called', function () {
            var $scope = {};
            var controller = $controller('MainCtrl', {$scope: $scope});

            $scope.inboxData = [{"subject": "Angular Example 11", "date": "3/8/2016", "to": "test1", "from":"abcd1","details":"Test Message 1" },{ "subject": "Angular Example 21", "date": "3/8/2016", "to": "test2", "from":"abcd2","details":"Test Message 2" },{ "subject": "Angular Example 31", "date": "4/8/2016", "to": "test3", "from":"abcd3","details":"Test Message 3" },{ "subject": "Angular Example 41", "date": "5/8/2016", "to": "test3", "from":"abcd4","details":"Test Message 4" }];
            $httpBackend.when('GET', 'inboxData.json').respond(yourjsonresponseData1);
$httpBackend.when('GET', 'inboxData2.json').respond(yourjsonresponseData2);
                var a=$scope.loadInboxData(1);
            expect($scope.inboxData).toEqual(a);

        }); 
    });


});
```